# How to set table ID from 0 in Play Framework?

Tags: postgresql, playframework, ebean

I didn't found how to do that
Please help me
ID started from 1, but I want to set its minimum value to 0
Is there any ways to do that?

Comment: Just for my curiosity, why would you want the id to start from 0 ?

Comment: This is server for my game, where location's ID starts from 0. I implemented this with extra field, but I think another solution is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in PostgreSQL primary key is serial, and it must start from 1
http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/datatypes/serial

Answer (score 0):

The EBean docs provide an example of how you can customize the ID generation - http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/jpa/id.